# Как обновить id элементов в базе данных (Django)

Tags: база-данных, django, queryset

Работаю с моделями в джанго, потребовалось сделать цикл

```
forwarder = Forwarder.objects.all()
sum_forwarders = forwarder.count()
for i in range(sum_forwarders):
    current_forwarder = Forwarder.objects.get(id=i).proj.all()
```

Но я получаю ошибку

```
bot.models.DoesNotExist: Forwarder matching query does not exist.
```

Суть в том, что я создал элемент, джанго ему присвоил `id=1`

После удаления элемента `id=1` на его месте образуется None

И при создании нового, он будет уже под `id=2`, а `id=1` так и останется со значением None

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какой способ можно обновлять это, либо в какой способ я могу пройти циклом начиная со значений, в которых имеется корректный id?

И вообще, почему все происходит именно в такой способ? 
Почему джанго не удаляет элемент вместе с его id?

Comment: Суть идентификаторов в их постоянстве, их нельзя изменять. Зачем использовать такой извращённый способ обхода? Почему не `for forwarder in Forwarder.objects.all()`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev потому что у меня имеется поле M2M и я не могу обратиться к его элементам, если буду использовать другой способ

Comment: Можете, поле m2m ничего не меняет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> И вообще, почему все происходит именно в такой способ? Почему джанго
>   не удаляет элемент вместе с его id?

Django ORM это только интерфейс для связи с БД, поле id ведет себя так потому что у него заданно такое поведение в SQL запросе "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"

> Подскажите пожалуйста, в какой способ можно обновлять это, либо в
>   какой способ я могу пройти циклом начиная со значений, в которых
>   имеется корректный id?

Не нужно ничего обновлять, вы просто "неправильно" делаете запросы к БД. Запрос должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
forwarders = Forwarder.objects.all()

for forwarder in forwarders:
    # делать что то
```

Что бы добавить в QuerySet поля m2m можно воспользоваться методом [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
forwarders = Forwarder.objects.all().prefetch_related('имя поля')
```